# Reference of Latex/Plain Tex control sequences

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, documentation, latex-base

I'm looking for a reference of the control sequences defined in Latex and plain Tex similar to [this](http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html) one for the build-in primitives.

The Texbook states that there are about 600 macros in plain Tex. How many are defined in the Latex format?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: As control sequences can be defined at point of use, it's not really possible to give a definitive list of control sequences. That's true for plain but even more so for LaTeX. Perhaps you could give us an idea of the target here?

Comment: I don't know how extensive this is, but I guess http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex2e-help-texinfo could be of interest.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: I know that i can define my own control sequences just like I can define my own functions in for example C. Most programming languages define a core language and a standard library. Other libraries or individual functions are build using these tools. From what I understand the 'core language' Tex are the 325 control sequences referenced in the link above. Plain TeX is somewhat like the standard library of TeX and Latex a high-level library. As I have a reference for the core language I'm looking for references for the other parts as well ... maybe my analogy is wrong though.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: by "in the latex format" do you mean actually in `latex.fmt` or do you mean "typically used with latex" for example commands such as `\rm` or `\figure` or `\maketitle` or `\section`  are not defined in the format but are defined by class files included in the core distribution.

Comment: @David Carlisle -- I was not aware the `\figure` or `\maketitle` isn't defined in `latex.fmt` thanks for pointing out. I have been using latex mostly as blackbox for the last year and now I want to understand what is defined where and what abstraction is build on top of what other abstractions. I thought of formats as a collection of macros that are implemented by means of  the core language (and other macro packages). Is that wrong? Many thanks ...

Comment: @jules well it's not completely wrong but after making a certain number of definitions they are dumped (using `\dump`0 into a format which is basically a binary dump of the internal memory state at that point. but when you go `\documentclass{article}` `\documentclass` is defined in the format but it then inputs `article.cls` which defines loads more commands _at that time_ including all the common sectioning commands.

Comment: A literal answering of your question would need to document internal commands like `\@err@                                                                 %` (with that many spaces in its name:-) but not top level user commands like `\section` that isn't really possible in a "quick reference" so the only answer is to read the documented sources, `texdoc source2e` in texlive at least.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle To `\@err@                                                                  %` is human... to `LaTeX`, divine.

Comment: @jules LaTeX doesn't load the plain TeX format, although LaTeX2e does define many of the plain commands (not all, though). You also need to watch the fact that commands can be redefined: LaTeX's `\end` is very different from the `\end` primitive! (The latter is saved by LaTex2e as `\@@end`)

Comment: @Joseph Wright thanks for the insight - the TeX ecosystem is way bigger then I expected!